# Why does modifying something in an array not change the same object outside of it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, reference

So for example I have something like this:

```
var foo = "foo";
var arr = [];
arr[0] = foo
arr[0] += " bar";
console.log(foo);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Why is the output

```
>>"foo"
>>"foo bar"
```

and not

```
>>"foo bar"
>>"foo bar"
```

?

Comment: strings are immutable, which means they never change once defined. they are also essentially "passed by value", which means you're duplicating when you assign the primitive to the object.

Comment: You are calling foo the string in your first output, not the foo from the array. The only value you actually changed was the value in the array.

You have 2 variables:
foo
arr

if you change arr, foo stays the same. If you change foo, then arr changes as well.

Comment: @dandavis if it was a variable, it would now contain the concated string: `var a = "foo";
a += " bar"
a;
"foo bar"`

Comment: Is the only way around it to reassign and do `foo = arr[0]?`

Comment: the way around it is to use a name a dot and a property in your assignment instead of just a name.

Comment: @user3731656 yes, you aren't assigning a new value to foo this way, you are assigning a value to arr[]

Comment: @Esailija: just like arr[0] does in the question. "+=" creates a new string/number in the place of the old right?

Comment: @dandavis oh, never mind then